# JSON and Scala parser

Tags: json, scala, jackson-databind

I'm trying to parse below code json string value:

```
val map1 = mapper.readValue("""{"test":"113123","myList":{"test2":"321323","test3":"11122"}}""", classOf[Map[String,Any]])
System.out.println(map1)
```

for that i'm getting output something like this:

```
Map(test -> 113123, myList -> Map(test2 -> 321323, test3 -> 11122))
```

But my expected output would be:

```
Map(test -> 113123, myList -> Some(Map(test2 -> 321323, test3 -> 11122)))
```

Need help to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: what does your mapper look like ?

Comment: I guess it's this ... http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-data-binding/ ... is that right?

Comment: i.e. an instance of the `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` class

Comment: @joelb, it would be dynamic JSON and we are not using any kind of POJO class over here

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for `Some()` as a value in your map, presumably there'd be some case where you'd expect a `None`. Rather than the `Option` be built-in to your map (perhaps with `classOf(Map[String, Option[Any]])`), I would have expected an `Option` to be returned on trying to access values from your map, as in `Map.get("myList")`, otherwise I'm not sure how you'd define that you didn't  also want `Map("cat" -> None, "dog" -> None, "fish" -> None)` etc.

In short, it looks to me like the `Some` is in an odd place

Comment: Yes if map contains value then we will use Some prefix otherwise there won't be any some prefix, like below
Map(test -> 113123, "cat" -> None, myList -> Some(Map(test2 -> 321323, test3 -> 11122)))

Comment: how do you plan on differentiating between e.g. `test->113123` and `myList -> Some(Map(...))`. That is, one uses Option, the other not. How come?

Comment: If it's None or single (k.v) means without option. If it's nested (k.v) means Some(Map(...))

Comment: I wouldn't do it this way (not saying I'm right), but if you want to, I can only think of making a type `T` as you describe, then putting it into `classOf[Map[String,T]]`. I don't know what that type would be

Comment: Could you please share more about this solution?

Comment: I don't know how you'd construct it because it would have to be a union of every valid value in JSON, but with Map replaced by Some(Map). AFAICT it's just an odd type